# Block rest of the view except a particular element

Tags: javascript, html

Sorry for the title couldn't come with a better one...
Okay here's is my doubt, when we display a javascript alert using  `alert("Some text")`  we see the alert dialog , Now the enter UI except the dialog box is unresponsive unless we hit `Ok` or close the alert window, Same goes for the `confirm` dialog.
 I am trying to build a widget to display my custom `Confirm` dialog using HTML elements but I don't know how to block the UI, The user if he wants can ignore the dialog & click other elements on the UI, Any suggestions or workarounds on blocking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could build a simple overlay with your dialog.  Your dialog could be absolutely positioned on the screen, allowing users to either click it or other elments to the side of it.

http://www.emanueleferonato.com/2007/08/22/create-a-lightbox-effect-only-with-css-no-javascript-needed/

Comment: perfect Thanks :) This is what I was looking for instead of all those jQuery plugins